# A rule of thumb of answer satisfaction?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, up-votes

So one rule of thumb I've noticed is that if the upvotes of a question is more than the upvotes of any of the answers. Then somehow the community feels the question was not answered satisfactorily. (This is more of an observation)

For people who like to answer questions this might be a useful filter. How do I see/create such a filter? The intention is to use this as a criteria for random bumping of questions.

Comment: *"[...]if the upvotes of a question is more than the upvotes of any of the answers. Then somewhere the community feels the question was not answered satisfactorily."* A highly questionable assumption. A question can have more upvotes than an answer simply because the question was posted *before* the answer and people don't get notified when an answer is posted to a question they upvoted. If it takes a few days for a "good" answer to come in this can be the entire reason the answer has less upvotes than the question.

Comment: @ACuriousMind which why I wanted a recent dataset and just see the applicability for 10 questions chosen randomly? Also if my rule of thumb is correct then after a while it will normalize in the use case you are talking about. But either way data first theories later?

Comment: hm, yeah i mean i upvote questions if i also wondered the same thing and am glad someone posted it, so i also agree this is a questionable assumption. i avoid upvoting answers at times because i do not feel i am enough of an expert to upvote, as i see upvoting as a kind of verification that the answer is right and/or legitimate.

Answer (score 6):

You want to write a query using the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/help). I don’t speak SQL fluently enough to freestyle a query for you here, but there is [a stack overflow tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataexplorer) for well-formed questions.  Questions and answers both live in the `Posts` table, but have different `PostTypeId`s, and answers have a `ParentId` which refers to their question; both types of post have a `Score`.

If such a query exists (perhaps because it’s the future and someone has written it), it’d be appropriate to link and describe in a separate answer to this Meta question.